# greengrass ggc_user changeable?

Tags: raspberry-pi, aws-iot, aws-greengrass

While installing AWS IoT Greengrass for Raspberry Pi, there is a need to create ggc_user & ggc_group as mentioned in [Greengrass developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/module1.html) step 9:

```
sudo adduser --system ggc_user

sudo addgroup --system ggc_group
```

<strike>Q1) Is it possible to use another user & group or customize?</strike>

<strike>Q2) What other configurations will be required to change in raspberry pi setup or greengrass setup or AWS Console then to make greengrass work on pi?</strike>

EDITED QUESTION: if rename ggc_user name to XYZ_user, why do greengrass-sdk stop working? Do i need to use this new username on any other files or setup/config of greengrass?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a specific user/group?

Comment: @hardillb it is part of instructions which is out of my reach to alter. i am actually trying to make solution which will run from windows host and will automatically (and somewhat blindly) setup "targeted solution" to new raspberry pi clients. and i believe the ggc_user is required to customize as part of this desired solution's security aspect.

Comment: That doesn't really explain why you want to change the user/group. Edit the question to include why you want to change it and what benefit you think it will give you.

Comment: @hardillb As i mentioned earlier, it is kind of security aspect requirement. Mainly there is no out-of-box setting allowed and therefore i want to use custom username/group instead of fixed ggc_user. i hope that clarifies the purpose. Thanks

Comment: As I said **EDIT** the question, and changing the name of the group/user makes no difference to the security as the user won't be able to logon to the machine no matter what you name it

Comment: @hardillb I edited question 2 for better understanding of scope of config/settings change in application level or os level or greengrass-sdk level. I am expecting answer on Q2 from this platform if Q1 answer is YES. If it is hard-coded rule by AWS and cannot be allowed to change then Q2 is not required. Thanks

Comment: You've still not explained the problem you are actually trying to solve by change the name. As I said changing the name will have no impact on security and will most likely just break things that expect the user/group to have that name

Comment: The edit still doesn't answer the WHY you want to do this, as I have already said, changing things for the sake of changing things does not automatically make it more secure. The username is listed as a prerequisite Greengrass Code code and as such it is safe to assume that the username hardcoded into the core daemon code and can not be changed.

Comment: @hardilib thanks for reply. as i had mentioned earlier, i am unable to disclose everything on public platform as part of my NDA. meanwhile, lets assume that i changed the username, what other places i will have to change this name? or is it impossible due to hardcoded or closed code of AWS?